# Reshaping from long to wide with multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a longitudinal survey dataset. I want to transform from long to wide so I can determine discrepancies from the first wave to the second wave. I am struggling to transform in R, as this was relatively straightforward coming from a Stata user.

I have a ID and time column with two different response columns. I want the transformed response columns to take the value of the time column in a wide format, but struggling with the code. I get a resulting dataframe with NAs.

```
df <- tibble(PIN = c(1001, 1001, 1002, 1002), time = c(1, 2, 1, 2), age = c(84, 86, 22, 24), height = c(58, 58, 60, 62))
df_wide <- reshape(df, 
                timevar=c("time"),
                idvar=c("PIN"),
                dir="wide")
```

**Input:**

| id | time | age | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 84 | 58 |
| 1001 | 2 | 86 | 58 |
| 1002 | 1 | 22 | 60 |
| 1002 | 2 | 24 | 62 |

**Desired Output:**

| id | age_t1 | age_t2 | height_t1 | height_t2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 84 | 86 | 58 | 58 |
| 1002 | 22 | 24 | 60 | 62 |

**Actual Output:**

| id | age.c(1,2) | height.c(1,2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | NA | NA |
| 1002 | NA | NA |

Comment: Note that your solution was correct is you just convert the `tibble` to a data.frame: `df_wide <- reshape(as.data.frame(df), timevar=c("time"),
 idvar=c("PIN"), dir="wide"); df_wide`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pivot_wider` may be easier

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(time = str_c('t', time)) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = c(age, height))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
    PIN age_t1 age_t2 height_t1 height_t2
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1  1001     84     86        58        58
2  1002     22     24        60        62
```

---

With `reshape` from `base R`, it may need a sequence column

```
out <- reshape(transform(df, rn = ave(seq_along(PIN), PIN,
   FUN = seq_along)), idvar = "PIN", 
    direction = "wide", timevar = "time", sep = "_")
out[!startsWith(names(out), 'rn_')]
   PIN age_1 height_1 age_2 height_2
1 1001    84       58    86       58
3 1002    22       60    24       62
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative,

```r
data.table::dcast(as.data.table(df), PIN ~ time, value.var = c("age", "height"))
#      PIN age_1 age_2 height_1 height_2
#    <num> <num> <num>    <num>    <num>
# 1:  1001    84    86       58       58
# 2:  1002    22    24       60       62
```

In many ways, `data.table::dcast` is very similar to `reshape2::dcast`, but this is one place that they differ: the use of multiple `value.var`s is not supported in `reshape2::dcast` (as far as I can tell).